# WebPiCMD.exe with Remote PowerShell Execution when installing .NET Framework 4

Tags: powershell, web-platform-installer

Has anybody had any luck using the WebPICmd.exe to automate the installation of .NET Framework 4 remotely. I am trying to do it with PowerShell and it does not seem to be working.

`PS C:> ([wmiclass]"\webserver1\root\cimv2:Win32_Process").Create("D:\installer_tools\webpicmd\webpicmd.exe /Install /Products:NETFramework4 /AcceptEula", "D:\installer_tools\webpicmd\")`

To add more detail, I keep getting this error: 

`Exe (C:\Users\rh\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Setup_4.0.30319\Windows6.1-KB958488-v6001-x64.msu) failed with 0x5 - Access is denied.`

Comment: webserver1 is a domain member server or a stand alone server?

Comment: @Christian WebServer1 is a domain member server, and I can install other products using the same technique described above but I haven't been able to pinpoint why the .NET Framework 4 installer fails miserably.  I figure somebody out there has got to know a workaround.

Comment: It seems to be near this issue http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxsetup/thread/b7127d2c-c295-484a-8903-a31dfc0348df  have you tried with administrator credentials?

Comment: @Christian Yes, running on an account with Administrative Privileges.

Comment: Ok, but in the previous link user need to set ACL permission to user or use administrator account. Maybe same problem as your. The error 0x05 Access Denied  seem to indicate privileges problem I think.. I can't reproduce your problem I'm on a different environment, but try to look better on ACL. Hope this can help you.

Comment: @Christian I will give the SubInACL fix detailed in that forum a try. I will keep you posted, Thanks.

Comment: @Christian No luck! Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I could get this to work was by using PsExec.exe tools from sysinternals and using /s option to have the process run under the system account. Just thought other people might find this information helpful.

SysInternals PsTools Download
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649

Option 1 - Using .NET Framework 4 Full Installer

```
.\_tools\PsTools\PsExec.exe \\WebServer1 /S /AcceptEula C:\installer\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe /q /norestart
```

Option 2 - Using WebPiCMD.exe

```
.\_tools\PsTools\PsExec.exe \\WebServer1 /S /AcceptEula C:\installer\_tools\WebPiCMD\WebPICMD.exe /Install /Products:NetFramework4 /AcceptEula
```

To download PSExec tools using the following code before one of the options above:

```
# Download Psexec
    $psToolsPath = "$env:temp\pstools"
    New-Item $psToolsPath -ItemType directory -force -erroraction silentlycontinue
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip -OutFile $psToolsPath\PSTools.zip

    #Expand and execute as local system
    Expand-Archive "$psToolsPath\PSTools.zip" $psToolsPath -force
    cd $psToolsPath
```

Answer (score 0):

To add on roberto's answer (can't comment yet), download PSExec tools using the following code before one of the options in his answer:

```
# Download Psexec
    $psToolsPath = "$env:temp\pstools"
    New-Item $psToolsPath -ItemType directory -force -erroraction silentlycontinue
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip -OutFile $psToolsPath\PSTools.zip

    #Expand and execute as local system
    Expand-Archive "$psToolsPath\PSTools.zip" $psToolsPath -force
    cd $psToolsPath
```